# UIWebview not fetching the linked CSS resource

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am trying to load a local html content into uiwebview. I already have the html content ready with me, and i am adding a reference a online css file to the content by the mechanism as shown in the code below. However, the problem i am facing is when i load the webview, there is no styling. Also, I verified in the Charles Proxy, there is no outgoing call for fetching iphone.css file to my base server. Ideally, while loading a html page, uiwebview should get all the referred resources, but for some reason unknown to me, it is not fetching the css file.

Please review and let me know if there is some issue with my code that i am not able to identify here?

```
NSString* htmlString = @"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"> <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"he\" lang=\"he\"><head><link type=\"text/css\" href=\"http://<base_server>/resources/iphone.css\" /><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" /></head><body>%@</body></html>";


        UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:htmlString,entry.body]);
        [webview loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:htmlString,entry.body] baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://<base_server>/"]];

        [self addSubview:webview];
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell if there are any typos in the HTML with all of the double quote escaping going on in that string. Why don't you pull the HTML out of the string and into a file, read that file in and place your content in the body. There may be a mistake with the markup in that string. This would allow you to read it easier in a seperate file.

Something like:

```
NSError *error;
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *htmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Sample" 
                                                         ofType: @"html"];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFilePath 
                                             usedEncoding:&encoding 
                                                    error:&error];

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlString, entry.body];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

[webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```